# Delphi XE Can't play sounds on Android device

Tags: android, delphi, firemonkey, delphi-xe8

I use TMediaPlayer and the following procedure:

```
procedure TForm1.PlayAudio(ResourceID: string);
var
  ResStream: TResourceStream;
  TmpFile: string;
begin
  ResStream := TResourceStream.Create(HInstance, ResourceID, RT_RCDATA);
  try

    //TmpFile := TPath.Combine(TPath.GetTempPath, 'tmp.wav');
    TmpFile :=(System.IOUtils.TPath.GetDocumentsPath + System.SysUtils.PathDelim + 'tmp.wav');

    ResStream.Position := 0;
    ResStream.SaveToFile(TmpFile);
    MediaPlayer1.FileName := TmpFile;

    MediaPlayer1.Play;

  finally
    ResStream.Free;
  end;
end;
```

To play sounds from my resources like this: `PlayAudio('Resource_1');` which are .wav and .mp3

It works fine on Windows but when I deploy it on Android it won't play any sounds, and I still can't find well explained way to play sounds on android from my resources. What is the best way to do so?

Comment: Delphi XE does not target Android. Which version of Delphi are you really using?

Comment: Resource files are only supported on Windows platform [Resource Files](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Resource_Files_Support)

Comment: On Android, you have to deploy the audio file as an asset, you can't embed it in the app executable itself. Then your app can use the filename of the deployed audio file as needed. [Loading and Deploying Files](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Seattle/en/Creating_an_Android_App#Loading_and_Deploying_Files)

Comment: @DavidHeffernan Delphi XE8, firemonkey

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks, I will try that later today.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks @RemyLebeau for pointing out that I need to find my path to resources using

```
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetDocumentsPath, 'filename')  { Internal }
TPath.Combine(TPath.GetSharedDocumentsPath, 'filename')  { External }
```

if Im deploying to android, but the files still couldn't run, and then I realized that I was using .mp3 and .wav. **I converted them to .3gp and now sound works just fine on android.**